# Function return a function that returns a function

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I would like to have a function returning a function that returns a function with the same signature as the first function. I.e. the function should be able to provide itself as a return value.

Is this possible in swift?

Example (this does not compile!):

```
typealias nextStep = ((char: CChar) -> nextStep)

func process(char: CChar) -> nextStep {...}
```

Comment: I think the reason it doesn't compile is because, since nextStep returns nextStep returns nextStep etc., at the end of this chain, nextStep will always return a nextStep which isn't a type.

Comment: Agree, but is there another way in which the intention of the code can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thomas's answer should work, but if you want a more typesafe alternative:

```
struct F {
    let f: (Character) -> F
}

func f(ch: Character) -> F {
    println("I've been called with an \(ch)!")
    return F(f: f)
}

let g = f("a")
let h = g.f("b")
h.f("c")
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution compiles. Don't know yet about runtime, but it is conceptually sound, so it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Any`like this:

```
typealias nextStep = ((char: CChar) -> Any)

func process(char: CChar) -> nextStep {
  return process
}
```

Comment: I already accepted this answer, but am now having difficulties in calling the returned function. Any tips on that? (I keep running into the error message "'Any' is not convertible to '(CChar)->Any'")

Comment: I added `let p = process(CChar()) as nextStep` which did compile but got a runtime error when using `p` the next time. Hmmm...

Comment: I guess you better go with Airspeed's solution. This works in any way. I got no idea why the above results in a runtime error.